# Custom control problem with variables

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I am creating a custom control for the first time and I have this as a part of the code :

```
    protected Pen pen;
    protected Color lineColor = Color.Green;
    protected double xMin = -10, xMax = 10, yMin = -10, yMax = 10;
    protected double[] data;

    public Graph()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(lineColor), 1);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        if(yMin <= 0 || yMax >= 0)
        {
            double yDifference = Math.Abs(yMin) + Math.Abs(yMax);
            double xAxisHeight = (Math.Abs(yMin) / yDifference) * Height;

            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, (int)xAxisHeight), new Point(Width, (int)xAxisHeight));
        }
    }
```

But for some reason xMin, xMax, yMin and yMax are always 0 in the onPaint function.

Edit :

Here is the rest of the code from Graph.cs

```
   The only this I wasn't showing was this : 

        public double XMin
    {
        get { return xMin; }
        set
        {
            xMin = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
    public double XMax
    {
        get { return xMax; }
        set
        {
            xMax = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
    public double YMin
    {
        get { return yMin; }
        set
        {
            yMin = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
    public double YMax
    {
        get { return yMax; }
        set
        {
            yMax = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public double[] Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set
        {
            data = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public Color LineColor
    {
        get { return lineColor; }
        set
        {
            lineColor = value;
            pen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(lineColor), 1);
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I bet ya it's being set to 0 somewhere in the code you aren't posting.

Comment: Are the values 0 before base.OnPaint is called?

Comment: Yup, I checked by  stopping the code at the constructor and everything was as its supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jimmy_keen's answer is correct.  If you have any public properties on your control, the designer will provide a UI for configuring them.  If you don't configure them, then the designer will set all the properties to their default values -- which in this case would be `default(int)` (that is, `0`), not the value that you initially set it to in your code.

But the solution isn't to just edit the code in the `*.Designer.cs` files directly, because Visual Studio will just put it back.  Instead, go to the properties for your custom control in the Designer and set some useful values.

Or, if you really don't want to be able to configure your control using the designer, you can use code like the following:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
[Browsable(false)]
public double XMin
{
    get { return xMin; }
    set
    {
        xMin = value;
        this.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

See the documentation on [`DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks this is a much better sollution then I had,

Answer (score 1):

Designer most likely sets your properties to default value, which is 0.

Try using [`DefaultValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx) attribute, just make sure both values (the one you initialize property backing field with and default one are the same):

```
private double xMin = -10;

[DefaultValue(-10)]
public double XMin
{
    get { return xMin; }
    set
    {
        xMin = value;
        this.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Both of the answers (this one and the one below didn't work )

Comment: @Quincy: can you try yet another attribute then? This seems to work best on my machine, previous one was dodgy.

Comment: Do you set the attributes when you include your control in markup? If not, try to comment one out and see if the backing-store gets set to 0. That will tell you if the designer is doing the deed or not.

Comment: @Quincy: there's 2 designers in play here: one that you use to design your custom control, and the second one where you design components/forms using your freshly designed control. This solution solves second issue - to have different values at control design time, you probably need different approach.

Comment: Wow your right, I looked into the MainForm designer.cs and this is what I found :this.graph1.XMax = 0D;
            this.graph1.XMin = 0D;
            this.graph1.YMax = 0D;
            this.graph1.YMin = 0D; So I am just going to delete that

Answer (score 0):

If the designer is setting them back to zero, after Initialize components set the values.  For instance

```
InitializeComponent();
xMin = -10;
xMax = 10; 
yMin = -10;
yMax = 10;
```

because it would be setting them to 0 inside the initialize components, which should be after the ones outside the constructor.